# libgit2sharp get commits between and including

Tags: libgit2sharp

I'm using filter with QueryBy to get the commits that I'm interested in.

```
// Set the filter 
CommitFilter filter = null;
filter = new CommitFilter()
{
  IncludeReachableFrom = "85494c32921c136cc3381fc14a3a20e08012c514",
  ExcludeReachableFrom = "63c8cb9ed585c0f3b79b6e2efc067e254910f875"
};
// Get the commits
repo.Commits.QueryBy(filter)
```

The QueryBy will not return the 63c8cb9ed585c0f3b79b6e2efc067e254910f875 commit, it will return the commits between the two.

Is there a way to have the 63c8cb9ed585c0f3b79b6e2efc067e254910f875 commit included as well ?

Maybe there another way available that I can use to get to the previous 63c8cb9ed585c0f3b79b6e2efc067e254910f875 from the commit that came after 63c8cb9ed585c0f3b79b6e2efc067e254910f875 and is returned by the query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **parents** of the `Commit` as list of commit pointers for your `ExcludeReachableFrom` filter.

#### Example:

```
    var filter = new CommitFilter
    {
        IncludeReachableFrom = "824201fcb8d4fa79b0aafa7c5aea86643cdd118a",
        ExcludeReachableFrom = repo.Lookup<Commit>("bcd85da0e287a3b404d12f8b666888962f692076").Parents
    };
    var commits = repo.Commits.QueryBy(filter);
    foreach (var commit in commits)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{commit.Sha}");
    }
```

#### Output:

```
824201fcb8d4fa79b0aafa7c5aea86643cdd118a
934fa3892acb2a48f296b7afc66b07125fb6db91
da995a21dc3fd038173695776fc1a3f4ff64f6ab
a9ee8086e5647141087c90909cd847a5fa5f294e
6313ca4b41dfef4d6b779f34f7b4807917c31188
bcd85da0e287a3b404d12f8b666888962f692076
```